# Создание картинки на лету

Tags: python, django

Есть HTML страница, которая создается шаблонами Django. На эту страницу проставляется внешняя ссылка с другого ресурса. Необходимо на лету создать для ссылки из страницы картинку (jpg, gif и т.п.). Внешняя ссылка выглядит просто

```
<img src=".../01234.png" width="200" height="50">
```

но картинка не статическая, а создается на лету, при обращении к ссылке. Как это можно сделать на Python/Django?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А в чём, собственно, проблема?
Берёте [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), рисуете нужную картинку. Создаёте response с правильным mime'ом: `response = HttpResponse(mimetype='image/png')`. Дальше вызываете стандартный метод Image.save, передав ему параметром response (который ведёт себя в точности как файл), а вторым аргументом, соответственно, 'PNG'. Возвращаете response. Дальше Джанго разберётся.

Answer (score 1):

Разницы нет какой фрейворк, какой язык и что Вы используете.
Достаточно понимать, что есть apache и что у него есть модуль mod_rewrite

Пишите .htaccess файл и записываете туда что-то подобное:

RewriteRule ^/some/path/([0-9]+).png$ /path/to/backend.php?i_want_this=$1

Естественно, что архитектура может быть другая, что вместо apache может быть nginx, что вместо .htaccess может быть что угодно, что вместо обработчика на php может быть любой другой, но суть остается всегда такой.

Comment: .htaccess-то тут каким боком? У джанго своя замечательная система разруливания URL'ов.

Comment: Я описал общий принцип, работать будет везде 100%. И .htaccess тут действительно никаким боком - ведь я так понимаю, что Django - это что-то сверхъестественное, выходящее за рамки веб-сервера :)
Если не знать как оно происходит никогда ничего не написать, "программист CMS" вовсе не программист, а сборщик, а по-русски "технарь".
Пусть хоть кто-нибудь скажет, что так работать не будет :)

Comment: Понимаете, Вы просто на вопрос совсем не ответили. Вопрос звучит так: «Как с помощью Джанго вывести в ответ на запрос картинку». Дажнго — это, действительно, что-то сверхъестественное. Подразумевается, что о том, как… мм… заставить веб-сервер выполнить какое-то действие при обращении по данной ссылке — и так понятно. В частности, это следует из того, что используется Джанго. Вы бы прежде чем отвечать на вопрос с меткой django, хоть почитал бы, что это такое ;).

Comment: Ох, не уйти бы по флейм — не для того мы здесь собрались. Короче, я Вам сказал, что Вы не правы — Вы, надеюсь, приняли это к сведению, но, в целом, отнеслись так, как угодно Вам. Предлагаю на том и сойтись :). В конце концов, рассудить нас должен автор вопроса и только он.

Answer (score 1):

Используй [sorl-thumbnail](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/index.html), очень удачное и удобное решение + автоматически кеширует изображения.